# Radium + LESS best practices?

Tags: reactjs, less, inline-styles

Is there better way to use Radium and LESS than `react-styling`?
Now use it in this way:

```
import styler from 'react-styling';
import base from '../../../basicStyles';

export default styler`
modalContent
  color: ${base.green}
`
```

But i don't like that i don't have LESS syntax highlighting and i have to pass props from base style using string template.